# For different words in a sentence, how can i get an output like A=B

Tags: python

I'm trying to find different words in 2 different sentence and my sentences inside of Excel's A row and B row.

```py
def UncommonWords(A, B): 

    res = len(test_string.split()) 
    count = {} 

    for word in A.split(): 
        count[word] = count.get(word, 0) + 1

    for word in B.split(): 
        count[word] = count.get(word, 0) + 1

    return [word for word in count if count[word] == 1]  


A = "wu tang clan"
B = "wu tang can"

print(UncommonWords(A, B)) 
print(A,'=',B)
```

A = "wu tang clan"
B = "wu tang can"
I have A and B sentences. As you can see 'clan' and 'can' words different.
I need an output like:

clan=can

So I dont want to match not unique words. And my A and B sentences always gonna change because i will get my sentences from Excel but my code just return me

wu tang clan=wu tang can

in my code return part give me an output like ['clan'],['can'] but this not seperated. I thought if i can seperate them like that 
'A sentence unique word: clan' as dif1
'B sentence unique word: clan' as dif2

i will put dif1 and dif2 to print(dif1,'=',dif2)
probably my output will ['clan=can'] and its so fine for me. By the way sorry for my English, thank you for helps.

<s>**Edit1:**</s>

```
 Specific examples:

 A = "put returns between two sentence"
 B = "put returns bet ween 2 sentence"

 Output should be like: between two = bet ween 2

 So i have to find unique words in A with in order then find in B, after that output should be as above.
```

**Edit2:**

```
 A = "a breath before surfacing"
 B = "a be before sura"

 Output should be like: breath=be|surfacing=sura

 uncommon_word_in_A[0] ?= uncommon_word_in_B[0]
 uncommon_word_in_A[1] ?= uncommon_word_in_B[1]
```

Comment: What is the desired output if A='some good thing here' and B='good old thing there'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def UncommonWords(A, B):
    A_list=A.split()
    B_list=B.split()
    uncommon_word_in_A = []
    uncommon_word_in_B = []
    i = 0
    for word in A_list:
        if word not in B_list:
            uncommon_word_in_A.append(word)


    for word2 in B_list:
        if word2 not in A_list:
            uncommon_word_in_B.append(word2)

    for i in range(0, len(uncommon_word_in_A)):
        print(uncommon_word_in_A[i], end=" ")

    print("=", end=" ")

    for i in range(0, len(uncommon_word_in_B)):
        print(uncommon_word_in_B[i], end=" ")


A = "put returns between two sentence"
B = "put returns bet ween 2 sentence"

UncommonWords(A, B)
```

**Output:**

```
 between two = bet ween 2
```

Comment: thats almost what i want just i need last 1 thing . my key counts will same at A and B. If A contain 4 words, B will 4 words too. So i wont surface with like words 'between->bet ween'. Actually its more simple. My last request from you, can you help me about how can I get output like at Edit2 ?

Comment: You can compare with if statement like: if str(uncommon_word_in_A) in A then print(like the code written above) else print (uncommon_word_in_A+"="+uncommon_word_in_B) for each element of list

Comment: dude im thinking about that until 1 hour and i couldnt work like you said. When you are avaible can you edit your code again? I swear my brain is not working

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is to be expected since you print your arguments instead of printing the result of the function (noticed the `return` statement at the end of the function ?). You'd want something like:

```
result = UncommonWords(A, B)
print("{} = {}".format(result[0], result[1])
```

**but** this blindly assumes you always have exactly one word of difference between your two strings - which will certainly not be the case for real data.

Also, your code is very inefficient. Using the builtin `set` type and it's `symmetric_difference` operation gives the same result in much less time and much less code:

```
print(set(A).symmetric_difference(set(B)))
```

Oh and yes, Python's naming conventions are `all_lower` for variables, functions and modules and `CamelCase` for classes.

Comment: I think I couldnt explain myself clearly. Python have a simple syntax but I started new, so I know my code is not inefficient and I want help. Thank you for answering but actually I need more clean code. symetric_difference gives me randomly differend keys. But my keys should be in order like in sentence.

Comment: @Battuvan dicts aren't ordered either (at least not before python 3.6.x, and it only became official in 3.7). And as I mentionned, the diffs between two strings can be anything so the result you expect doesn't make sense - what if  `A = "It won't work"` and `B = "I told you it wouldn't work"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for your reference

```
 def UncommonWords(A, B): 
    A = A.split()
    B = B.split()
    uncommon = [(A[i],B[i]) for i in range(0,len(A)) if not str(A[i])==str(B[i])]
    return uncommon


A = "wu tang clan"
B = "wu tang can"

uncommon = UncommonWords(A, B) 
print(['='.join([i[0],i[1]]) for i in uncommon])
```

Hope this helps